# Form Elements Not Going In Same Line

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, switch-statement, jsfiddle

Using jQuery mobile, I am trying to put a switch and a button in the same line, however it is not working and both elements are in separate lines:

Run:
http://jsfiddle.net/cHqsJ/

Code:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="switch">Privacy:</label>
    <select name="switch" id="switch" data-role="slider">
        <option value="0">Private</option>
        <option value="1">Public</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#switchinfo" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">Switch Info</a>
</div>
```

What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Three-column grids`. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/17/

```
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><label for="switch">Privacy:</label></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <select name="switch" id="switch" data-role="slider">
                        <option value="0">Private</option>
                        <option value="1">Public</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a href="#switchinfo" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog">Switch Info</a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /grid-b -->     
        </div>
```

*There is also `data-inline="true"` but the label would break another line.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/cHqsJ/1/